# Why won't my diff.exe run from cmd line?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've got a number of utilities installed in `C:\program files (x86)\git\bin`, many of which shadow built-in command line functions. So as not to run afoul of that, I would rather NOT add that folder to the PATH, however I do want to be able to type `diff a.txt b.txt` anywhere and run diff on the two.

Things I have tried:

- Added a `diff.exe` subkey to `[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths]`
- Created a `diff.lnk` in `C:\dev` (which is on my PATH) and added `.LNK` to my PATHEXT
- Created a `diff.bat` with the following code:

  `@"C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\diff.exe" *$`

The only method that worked was the last one, which (although it runs `diff`) fails to find any files I specify through the command line.

Similarly, the second method allowed `diff` to run if I was currently in `C:\dev` but not elsewhere.

I have a `doskey` script that works as an alias machine (notably: `npp=notepad++` on cmd start) but I would rather not resort to that for this. I will if I have to.

Any suggestions? Any idea why the above didn't work?

Comment: It should be %*, not *$.

Comment: A suggestion. Why don't you just create a link to the command prompt with a temporary PATH variable?

Comment: Why are you modifying the PATH environmental variables by the registry?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not?

Comment: Have you tried **@AFH** suggestion of `%*`, instead of `*$`, like `@"C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\diff.exe" %*` ?

Comment: What is the value of the **`"(default)"`** entry for your **`[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\diff.exe]`** key?

Comment: @KevinFegan No I haven't had a chance to get back on that computer. The value for the listed entry is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\diff.exe`

Comment: Does it work from a **`cmd.exe`** window if you type **`start [/wait] "" diff.exe a.txt b.txt`**? See the answers to this question: (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3114618/606539) and some of the comments there for some related info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why the above didn't work?

A few.

- `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` has no effect on `cmd`, because `cmd` doesn't use `ShellExecuteEx` to run programs.
- [Creating a `.lnk` file should have worked.](https://superuser.com/questions/227877/)  From your description, it seems the most probable that the statement

  > `C:\dev` is on my `PATH`.

  is not in fact true.
- `diff.bat` didn't work as you wanted because the syntax that you were using for substituting all positional parameters was gibberish.  `*$` isn't even an accidental bashism.  As noted, [`%*` is the correct syntax for doing that in scripts interpreted by `cmd`](https://microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx).  ([It is also the correct syntax for Take Command, which supports `%#` as a bonus.](http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?batchparms.htm))

Comment: RE: `*$`, I believe I confused that from `doskey`, where `doskey alias=command *$` is correct (perhaps it's `$*`? I'm copying from memory)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking doskey, whose syntax is `doskey alias=command $*`. I double checked my PATH environment variable and `C:\dev` was in fact on the PATH, however I moved it to a different folder (`C:\dev\path`) and it worked perfectly. That one I have no answer for. I'm sure your suggestion `%*` in a batch file would have worked as well, thank you!